# Error al cambiar de versión de php con Laragon en windows

Tags: php, laragon

Hola e instalar Laragon en windows 11, y al momento de cambiar de versión de PHP, descomprimiendo la carpeta en el directorio de PHP de Laragon, cuando lo intengo ejecutar me marca este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sucede con las versiones de PHP 8.1.12 y 8.2.12

Muchas gracias por su ayuda, saludos

Comment: pero esto no es un error de programacion, es un error de configuracion, tendrias que preguntar en el sitio de super usuarios.